# Spring Batch issue with commit-interval

Tags: spring-batch

I have written a spring batch program where I have implemented custom reader and writer classes.
When I keep commit-interval more than one then records get repeated to the commit interval size.
For e.g. I am reading data from my input csv file as
Id, Name
1, Akash
2, John
3, Daksh
And commit-interval="2"
In this case writer receives records as
1, Akash
1, Akash
3, Daksh
(first record gets repeated till commit-interval and then the records after commit-interval, the intermediate records gets skipped somewhere)

With commit-interval=1 every thing works fine but it impacts the performance drastically.

Please advise. 
Code snippet as below:

```
public class PGPFlatFileItemReader extends FlatFileItemReader<Object> 
implements InitializingBean {

/*
 * if this flag is true that means file
 * is commpressed
 */
private boolean isCompressed = true; 
private String passphrase;
private String secretKeyFilePath;
private String publicKeyFilePath;
private String publicKeyUserId;
private String inputFilePath;

public PGPFlatFileItemReader() {
    SecurityUtil.loadSecuritySetting();
}

/**
 * @return the isCompressed
 */
public boolean isCompressed() {
    return isCompressed;
}

/**
 * @param isCompressed
 *            the isCompressed to set
 */
public void setCompressed(boolean isCompressed) {
    this.isCompressed = isCompressed;
}

/**
 * @return the passphrase
 */
public String getPassphrase() {
    return passphrase;
}

/**
 * @param passphrase
 *            the passphrase to set
 */
public void setPassphrase(String passphrase) {
    this.passphrase = passphrase;
}

/**
 * @return the secretKeyFilePath
 */
public String getSecretKeyFilePath() {
    return secretKeyFilePath;
}

/**
 * @param secretKeyFilePath
 *            the secretKeyFilePath to set
 */
public void setSecretKeyFilePath(String secretKeyFilePath) {
    this.secretKeyFilePath = secretKeyFilePath;
}

/**
 * @return the publicKeyFilePath
 */
public String getPublicKeyFilePath() {
    return publicKeyFilePath;
}

/**
 * @param publicKeyFilePath
 *            the publicKeyFilePath to set
 */
public void setPublicKeyFilePath(String publicKeyFilePath) {
    this.publicKeyFilePath = publicKeyFilePath;
}

/**
 * @return the publicKeyUserId
 */
public String getPublicKeyUserId() {
    return publicKeyUserId;
}

/**
 * @param publicKeyUserId
 *            the publicKeyUserId to set
 */
public void setPublicKeyUserId(String publicKeyUserId) {
    this.publicKeyUserId = publicKeyUserId;
}

/**
 * @return the inputFilePath
 */
public String getInputFilePath() {
    return inputFilePath;
}

/**
 * @param inputFilePath
 *            the inputFilePath to set
 */
public void setInputFilePath(String inputFilePath) {
    this.inputFilePath = inputFilePath;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
    FileDecrypter fileDecrypter = new FileDecrypter();
    if (this.isCompressed) {

        this.uncompressFile(fileDecrypter.decryptFile(inputFilePath, secretKeyFilePath, passphrase.toCharArray(),
                "sample.txt", true, 2));

        inputFilePath = inputFilePath + Constants.INBOUND_UNC_FILE;

    }

    InputStream clearStream = fileDecrypter.decryptFile(inputFilePath, secretKeyFilePath, passphrase.toCharArray(),
            "sample.txt", false, 2);

    InputStreamResource in = new InputStreamResource(clearStream);

    this.setResource(in);

}

private void uncompressFile(InputStream unc)
        throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException, PGPException, SpringBatchException {

    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(unc));

    ArrayList<String> rawdata = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileEncrypter fileEncrypter = new FileEncrypter();

    PGPPublicKey encKey;

    String outFileName = inputFilePath + Constants.INBOUND_UNC_FILE;

    if (JavaUtil.isObjectNull(publicKeyFilePath)) {

        throw new SpringBatchException(ExceptionCodes.PUBLIC_KEY_NOTFOUND, "For Public Key Path");

    }
    encKey = SecurityUtil.readPublicKey(publicKeyFilePath, publicKeyUserId);

    String line = bufferRead.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        if (rawdata.size() < Constants.batchSize) {
            rawdata.add(line + "\n");
        } else if (rawdata.size() == Constants.batchSize) {
            rawdata.add(line + "\n");
            StringBuilder RecordsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String record : rawdata) {
                RecordsBuilder.append(record);
            }
            fileEncrypter.encryptBigText(outFileName, RecordsBuilder.toString(), encKey, false, true);
            rawdata.clear();
        }
        line = bufferRead.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            for (String record : rawdata) {

                if (rawdata.size() > 0) {
                    fileEncrypter.encryptBigText(outFileName, record, encKey, false, true);
                }
            }
            rawdata.clear();
        }
    }

    if (rawdata.size() > 0) {
        for (String record : rawdata) {
            fileEncrypter.encryptBigText(outFileName, record, encKey, false, true);
        }
    }

    FileEncrypter.setCalledForFirstTime(false);
    FileEncrypter.closeStreams();
    if (!JavaUtil.isObjectNull(FileEncrypter.fBufferedOut)) {
        FileEncrypter.fBufferedOut.close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What `ItemReader` are you using?  Please provide any relevant code and configuration so we can help diagnose.

Comment: @MichaelMinella : Have added the code snippet in question.